# Unsure how to web-scrape a specific value that could be in several different places

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I've been working on a web-scraping program and have been having some difficulties with one of the last bits.

There is this website that shows records of in-game fights like so:

Example 1: https://zkillboard.com/kill/44998359/

Example 2: https://zkillboard.com/kill/44917133/

I am trying to always scrape the full information of the player who scored the killing blow. That means their name, their corporation name, and their alliance name.

The information for the above examples are:

Example 1: Name = Happosait, Corp. = Arctic Light Inc., Alliance = Arctic Light

Example 2:  Name = Lord Veninal, Corp. = Sniggerdly, Alliance = Pandemic Legion

While the "Final Blow" is always listed in the top right with the name, the name does not have the corporation and alliance with it as well. The full information is always listed below in the right-hand column, "## Involved", but their location in that column depends on how much damage they did in the fight, so it is not always on top, or anywhere specific for that matter.

So while I can get their names with:

```
kbPilotName = soup.find_all('td', style="text-align: center;")[0].find_all('a', href=re.compile('/character/'))[0].img.get('alt')
```

How can I get the rest of their information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `textarea` element containing all the data you are looking for. It's all in one text, but it's structured. You can choose a different way to parse it, but here is an example using regex:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://zkillboard.com/kill/44998359/'

pattern = re.compile(r"(?s)Name: (.*?)Security: (.*?)Corp: (.*?)Alliance: (.*?)")

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

    response = session.get(url)    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    data = soup.select('form.form textarea#eft')[0].text

    for name, security, corp, alliance in pattern.findall(data):
        print name.strip()
```

Prints:

```
Happosait (laid the final blow)
Baneken
Perkel
Tibor Vherok
Kheo Dons
Kayakka
Lina Ectelion
Jay Burner
Zalamus
Draacan Ferox
Luwanii
Jousen Momaki
Varcuntis Morannear
Grimm K-Man
Wob'Niar
Godfrey Silvarna
Quintus Corvus
Shadow Altair
Sieren
Isha Vir
Argyrosdraco
Jack None
Strixi
```

---

Alternative solution (parsing "involved" page):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://zkillboard.com/kill/44998359/'
involved_url = 'https://zkillboard.com/kill/44998359/involved/'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

    session.get(url)

    response = session.get(involved_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    for row in soup.select('table.table tr.attacker'):
        name, corp, alliance = row.select('td.pilot > a')
        print name.text, corp.text, alliance.text
```

Comment: I definitely appreciate the help, I'll look more into your answer. However, it seems really long and I haven't been able to get alliance information to be printed with it nor a great way to actually select only the killing blow pilot's data out of it. :\

Comment: @Scarecrow ok, I can look for a different approach also. One question: basically you need to parse the "involved pilots" page (https://zkillboard.com/kill/44998359/involved/)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help; regarding the involved pilots page, ... Kind of? My program will be visiting the URL I gave, but it should be able to access that as well from it. As for the data, yes, I think the best way I can think of is to parse the "Involved Pilots" section. (Although I have to try and be sure I don't try and go to a new website off a link to get the data or it will cause more of a mess down the road)

Comment: @Scarecrow please see the updated answer providing an example code to parse name, corp and alliance from the "involved pilots" page. Hope this is what you were asking about and it puts you on the right track.

Comment: The new version won't run, I think I am going to just find a different work-around thank you anyway though. ^^

Comment: @Scarecrow what is happening on your end? Any errors? (the code works for me)

Comment: line 16, in <module>
    name, corp, alliance = row.select('td.pilot > a')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @Scarecrow hm, are you testing it against the same urls as in the answer?

Comment: Exactly copy and pasted what you had into a new program